# "Operator '<' cannot be applied to '<lambda parameter>', 'int' " in java

Tags: java, lambda, remove-if

I met a problem about doing operation between a `lambda parameter` and a `int`. Codes are written as follows:

```java
HashMap<Integer, Integer> testMap = new HashMap<>();
testMap.put(1, 1);
testMap.put(2, 2);
testMap.entrySet().removeIf((key, value) -> value < 100);
```

IDEA shows an error of `Operator '<' cannot be applied to '<lambda parameter>', 'int'`.
I am wondering why and if there is any way to fix the problem.

Comment: The type of your lambda should be Predicate<Entry<Integer,Integer>>, not something with two parameters.

Comment: `testMap.entrySet().removeIf(e -> e.getValue() < 100);`. Or depending on preference: `testMap.values().removeIf(v -> v < 100);`. The `removeIf` method of the entry set needs a `Predicate<? super Entry<Integer, Integer>>`, so before `->` you need to place one entry, not key and value separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Map#entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) returns a `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>`. `Set` inherits [`removeIf` from the `Collection` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-), which expects a `Predicate<? super E>`, namely a predicate with a single argument. `E` in this case is `Map.Entry<K,V>` (which is still only a single object, even though it holds two other values: a key and a value). Key and value can be accessed via `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods, respectively.

Your code is fixed easily:

```
testMap.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue() < 100);
```