# Operator '==' cannot be applied to '<lambda parameter>', 'int'

Tags: java, kotlin, video, webview, android-mediaplayer

I have a e-commerce website app which i was made from an online app making website. I need to update the app & after update the necessary dependence, i have faceing few problem.

First one [ Operator '==' cannot be applied to '<lambda parameter>', 'int' ]

I try to solve the problem but i cant please help me

Comment: Have you checked to see if this has already been asked and answered? Does this answer your question? ["Operator '<' cannot be applied to '<lambda parameter>', 'int' " in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72327658/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-lambda-parameter-int-in-java) .  If that doesn't answer you question, edit your question, and include enough code for us to understand the context. Check the box to request the question be reopened.